# Firestore: Use of unresolved identifier 'Firestore'

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to implement the Firestore Database. In my Podfile I added `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` and did `pod install`. When `trying to use let db = Firestore.firestore()`I get the Error:`Use of unresolved identifier 'Firestore'`. I have tried pod update too and it also says `Using FirebaseFirestore (0.12.2)` but it soll doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 35):

You need to import it.

Include `import FirebaseFirestore` at the top of your manager file.

Comment: I get `No such module 'FirebaseFirestore'` there as well. Before I had `import Firebase` and this works. But somehow Firestore does not. Also I find it suspicious that it in my terminal it says `Using FirebaseFirestore (0.12.2)` while the other Firebase imports are 5.0.x.

Comment: I find it strange that Google couldn't tell us this.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Answer (score 7):

I had to add `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` to the podfile and then reinstall the podfile.

Comment: You missed a quote `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'`

Answer (score 5):

If my guess is right. pod 'Firebase/Firestore' was installed after appname.xcworkspace was created by already installing pod once.
One solution is to remove all these ****appname.xcworkspace, ****Podfile.Lock, ****Pods Folder
and install pod once more. it should work.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486792/9547658

I don't know why it didn't worked in the first place but now it works...

Comment: Could have been a corrupt ModuleMap in DerivedData

Answer (score 3):

Using `var db: Firestore!` instead of `var db: FireStore!` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the build folder fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me, add pod 'Firebase/Firestore' to the podfile and import FirebaseFirestore

Credit to Pseudonym Patel
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53434443/12088138